# Query to select match id and other 2 diffrent ids

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query that will select three different rows matching the category and one matching id with a total of 3 results.

For example, I have this table called users:

users:

```
user_id     user_name   category_id     
1           Sally       1                         
2           Martin      1                          
3           Mary        1                            
4           John        1
5           Phil        1 
6           Erik        1
7           Joanna      2
```

As you can see, all users except Joanna belong to category 1. I need a query where a total of three users are selected from `category_id` 1, BUT out of those three results, on of the users MUST be `user_id` 3.

Can this be done with just one query?

This is what I came up with, but none of these work:

```sql
SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE category_id=1 AND user_id=3 LIMIT 3
```

or

```sql
SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE category_id=1 AND (user_id=3 or user_id!=3) LIMIT 3
```

I need the query to select three users from `category_id` 1, and one of the three MUST be `user_id` 3

Thanks!

Comment: That query does not guarantee user_id 3 will be in the results.

Comment: Yes you right. I removed my comment

Comment: What result should be returned if there are less than three rows with `category_id=1`, or if there isn't a row with `user_id=3 and category_id=1`, but at least three other rows in `category_id=1`.

Answer (score 4):

I think taking a `UNION` of two queries is a good option:

```
SELECT user_name
FROM users
WHERE category_id=1 AND user_id=3
UNION
SELECT user_name
FROM users
WHERE category_id=1 AND user_id <> 3
LIMIT 2
```

The first query will return the record where `user_id` is `3`, and the second query will retain a maximum of 2 records where `category_id` is also `1` but the `user_id` is *not* `3`.

Comment: I recommend using `ORDER BY RAND()` for the other two result

Comment: @WillyPt This is a good suggestion if the OP wants it.  I have been slammed before on Stack Overflow for ordering by `RAND()` because of "performance" concerns, so I will leave it out for now.